# What does the `cc` option `-ldl` do in the following command?

Tags: unix, x86

during compilation of dynlinktest.c it gives following error:

unipro@ubuguest:~$ **cc dynamiclinktest.c -o dynamiclinktest
/tmp/ccli8dp2.o: In function `main':
dynamiclinktest.c:(.text+0x53): undefined reference to`dlopen'
dynamiclinktest.c:(.text+0x83): undefined reference to `dlsym'
dynamiclinktest.c:(.text+0x109): undefined reference to`dlclose'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status**

after using cc dynlinktest.c -o dynlinktest -ldl it runs.
i didn't get why it is neccessary using `-ldl` ?

edit1: leaving space before error.

Comment: Try 'man cc'. It will give you some information about your compiler and its options.

Comment: The reason I introduced the spaces before your command line and error message was so that they would get formatted correctly; this is the convention that Stack Overflow uses to mark code and verbatim output. I would suggest you put the spaces back in to make the error message easier to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-ldl` includes the reference to the library that has the symbols for loading dynamic libraries (such as `dlopen`).